# Flask WTF to flask-mail attachment?

Tags: python, wtforms, flask-wtforms, flask-mail

Upload a file via flask-wtf and then mail it using flask-mail

```
def careers():
    form = CareersForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        msg = Message('my subject for message', sender = MAIL_USERNAME, recipients = [company_email])
        msg.html = "My message"
        with app.open_resource(form.resume) as fp:
            msg.attach("resume.pdf", "application/pdf", fp.read())
        mail.send(msg)

    return render_template('default/careers.html',form=form)
```

The error i get is `AttributeError: 'FileField' object has no attribute 'startswith'` ideal result would be for it to attach and send email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This program will upload a file and attach it to an email message. The email server settings are stored in `settings.py`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from flask import Flask, render_template_string
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, validators
from flask_wtf.file import FileField
from flask_mail import Mail, Message

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('settings')
mail = Mail(app)


class FileForm(FlaskForm):
    file_ = FileField('Some file')
    addr = StringField('Address', [validators.InputRequired()])


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def root():
    form = FileForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        msg = Message(
            'Sending file',
            sender=form.addr.data.strip(),
            recipients=[form.addr.data.strip()])
        msg.body = 'Sending file %s' % (form.file_.name)
        msg.attach(
            form.file_.data.filename,
            'application/octect-stream',
            form.file_.data.read())
        mail.send(msg)
        return "Sent"

    return render_template_string('''
        <html><body><form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            {{ form.addr.label }}: {{ form.addr() }}<br/>
            {{ form.file_.label }}: {{ form.file_() }}<br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Click Me!"/>
        </form></body></html>''', form=FileForm())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```